# How to join two conditions in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

**Note: Update Jun 28**

I have an iptables script.sh (interpreted by bash) with the rules:

```
function run_ips(){
for ip in $(sed '/#.*/d' ips.txt); do
  if echo $ip | grep -q "-" >/dev/null; then
    iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source $mac -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m iprange --dst-range "$ip" -j ACCEPT
  else
    iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source $mac -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -d $ip -j ACCEPT
  fi
done
}
for mac in $(awk -F";" '{print $2}' macs.txt); do
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source $mac -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
   iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source $mac -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
   run_ips
done
```

Where macs.txt contains macs addresses and ips.txt contains ips addresses or ranges separates with "-"

> Error: Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Perhaps you want to use the -w option?

(this is generated by function "run_ips")

How can I unify both parts?

Comment: You should use `$()` instead of `\`\``, which is deprecated

Comment: Are you asking how to nest for loops in bash?

Comment: The error you reported "Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Perhaps you want to use the -w option?" originates from `iptables` you are not showing up any code that interacts with `iptables`, please add the code causing the issue to your question

Comment: Update question with real rules. Thanks Will B. for the $() clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a need for a function here. If you do need a function, it might be best to pass the variable as a parameter, rather than attempting to use it as a global variable. However, it seems pretty straight forward to just nest the loops:

```
for mac in $(awk -F";" '{print $2}' macs.txt); do
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source $mac -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
    iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source $mac -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
    for ip in $(sed '/#.*/d' ips.txt); do
      if echo $ip | grep -q "-" >/dev/null; then
        iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source $mac -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m iprange --dst-range "$ip" -j ACCEPT
      else
        iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source $mac -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -d $ip -j ACCEPT
      fi
    done
done
```

As for the error message, it would seem that you have a process being run at the same time these rules are being processed. Perhaps you should just add `-w` to your iptables lines, as the error suggests. This option should causes iptables to wait for the xtables lock to release.